# I'm not sure why this xpath is unable to be located using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape every item on a site that's displayed in a grid format with infinite scrolling. However, I'm stuck on even getting the second item using xpath because it's saying:
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='el-card advertisement card is-always-shadow'][2]"}`

```
x = 1

while x < 5:
    time.sleep(5)
    target = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[@class='el-card advertisement card is-always-shadow'][{x}]")
    target.click()
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "details")))
    print(driver.current_url)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.back()
    time.sleep(5)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.title_contains("Just Sold"))
    time.sleep(5)
    x += 1
```

With my f-string xpath it's able to find the first div with that class and print the URL, but the moment it completes one iteration of the while loop, it fails to find the 2nd div with that class (so [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PUvq.png)).

I've tried monitoring it with all the time.sleep() to see exactly where it was failing because I thought maybe it was running before the page loaded and therefore it couldn't be found, but I gave it ample time to finish loading every page and yet I can't find the issue.

This is the structure of the HTML on that page:
[image]
There is a class of that name (as well as "el-card__body" which I have also tried using) within each div, one for each item being displayed.
[image]
(This is what each div looks like)

Thank you for the help in advance!

(disclaimer: this is for a research paper, I do not plan on selling/benefiting off of the information being collected)

Comment: You could try `targets = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='el-card advertisement card is-always-shadow']"` (note the plurals and removing the `[{x}]`) to find all the elements at once and see how many there are.

Comment: Its better to post the html as text. My search function doesn't work on images.

Comment: Just tried that and can confirm it makes a List of length 10 as it should (10 items are added every time you scroll past the page limit)

Comment: I don't know why your method doesn't work, but seems like the answer is to get them all with that command and the loop through the results.

Comment: What website is it from

Comment: Your approach worked, tdelaney. Thanks! I don't know why I didn't think of doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing each item in a list using `find_elements_by_xpath`, then iterating through them did the trick, as suggested by tdelaney.